# Can i somehow check my iPhone safari browser history with exact time?

Tags: safari, web-browser, history

I'm in court and I need to confirm by law something and the only way I can do it, is to offer the exact time I checked for a particular web page on that day. Can someone give me a software or a trick to uncover that data?

Comment: Huh, I just realized Mobile Safari's history doesn't show time visited...